# Vertical tabs with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

any one know how to use vertical tabs with jquery.
In my web site i want to use partial views i implemented it with jquery horizontal tabs but i want it with vertical tab as my links are in right side. so any one know the solution plz tel me. I am using asp.net mvc application
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [Online Demo](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html) of vertical tabs using jQuery UI. So... you should be able to either do this with jQuery UI (try that first), or download a pre-release version from SVN that supports it.